# __bridge_transfer from CFArrayRef to NSArray* - are elements transferred too?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, abaddressbook

I have worked with manual ref counting, ARC and CF objects for a while, but while working with the AddressBook API today I realized I don't understand one thing (and I couldn't find an explanation in the documentation either).

Here is my usecase: I'm copying a `ABMultiValueRef` property from an `ABRecordRef` (to get all of the elements).

```
ABMultiValueRef multiString = ABRecordCopyValue(personRef, propertyID);
NSArray* multiValues = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multiString);
CFRelease(multiString);

//do something with the multiValues NSArray
```

So I got a copy of a certain property of type `kABMultiStringPropertyType` which presents itself as a `CFArrayRef` of `CFStringRef`s. If I understand correctly, I am responsible for releasing both the `CFStringRef`s in the array and the `CFArrayRef` itself. (Maybe not, so please let me know if I'm wrong here).

After bridging the `CFArrayRef` from the CF world and transferring ownership to ARC, I know the `NSArray*` will be taken care of by ARC. But what about the `CFStringRef`s inside that array? They are bridged to `NSString*` (I know that, because I can iterate the elements with `for..in`), but I'm not sure which type of `__bridge*` was applied to it.

From experience and me not encountering this earlier, I would guess that whatever `__bridge*` is used (`__bridge` or `__bridge_transfer`) on the array, the same one is used on the elements in that array.

Is that correct? Again, I couldn't find a confirmation anywhere, so if you know a place in the documentation which specifies it, I would greatly appreciate any info about it. Thanks.

//Edit after getting an answer

I did not realise both `CFArray` and `NSArray` retain their elements - and that's the case both in the CF and object worlds, so nothing has to change during the `__bridge*`. After transfered, the `NSArray` is taken care of by ARC and its elements are taken care of by the array itself. So when ARC releases the array, the array releases its elements (so ARC does not need to know anything about the elements).

Comment: The bridge directives simply supply ARC with information on what it should do relative to retain and release. In both CFArray and NSArray, objects are retained when added and released when removed, so ARC does nothing with them. I cannot think of any case where bridge affects anything other than the two objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__bridge_transfer` or `__bridge` is "only" a type cast plus an optional transfer of ownership.
The array itself it not modified by the brigde, and the array
elements do not change at all.

So you are not responsible for releasing the array elements. The array retains its
elements (ARC speak: keeps strong references), and releases them (removes the
strong reference) when the elements are removed from the array.

Only if you explicitly transfer the ownership of an array element you are
responsible for releasing it:

```
CFStringRef s = (__bridge_retain CFStringRef) multiValues[0];
// …
CFRelease(s);
```

Comment: Of course. For some reason I did not realise the array needs to retain its elements, meaning when ARC releases the array, the array "manually" releases its elements. This explains my question, thanks.